# Recovering from: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Every now and than I loss the connection in SSMS and get the message

```
Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
```

The annoying thing is, that the button to change the connection ("Verbindung ändern" for me) is inactive, and I have to open a new tab, open the connection and copy the contents of the inactive window to it.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue after installing SSMSToolsPack. If I have a window that is connected to multiple servers, then open a new window, there is no way to get that window to connect. I have to close the window as both the "Connect" and "Change Connection" buttons are inactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2005 at least, hit F5 to re-run your query. SSMS will determine it is no longer connected and then prompt you to reconnect. If I recall correctly, 2005 will put you back into the same database while 2008 puts you into your default catalog. A second execution of F5 will actually run the command. I've never had a semaphore timeout but it works for other disconnect scenarios.

Comment: I agree, with the mention that also SSMS 2008 will put you into the same previous database.

Comment: It seems to depend. If the connection to the server was lost, it goes to the default catalog, if only the connection to the database was lost, it reconnects to this database. (tested on SQL Server 2008)